# Post hidden field containing javascript variable or function?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I feel like I must be missing something, or I'm just too clueless to search for the right question, so please pardon me (and redirect) if this is a duplicate.  My issue is probably much harder than I think it should be.

I have a page with a rather lengthy block of php code (mainly MySQL queries) which generate variables that are eventually passed into JavaScript as strings. The data is then used to create some interactive form elements.  The end result is a textarea field which contains a JS string which I'd like to carry into to a new page.  I will also be POSTing php variables to that new page.

Sample code:

```
<?php //Get data from MySQL, define variables, etc.?>

<script> //Move php strings into JavaScript Strings; 
         //put JS vars into textareas; etc 
         var foo = document.getElementById('bar').value </script>

<form action="newpage.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name = "name" value="**JAVASCRIPT foo INFO HERE**"/>
<input type = "hidden" id="id2" name = "name2" value = "<?php echo $foo; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
```

Calling JS functions in the right order is a little sticky because they depend on php variables which aren't defined until queries are complete, so I can't do much with an onload function. I'm literate in php.  I'm a novice in JavaScript.  I'm fairly inept with JQuery and I've never used AJAX.  I'd also really rather not use cookies.

It would be great to see an example of what the original and new page code might look like.  I know I can receive the php on the new page info via

```
$foo = $_POST['name2'];
```

beyond that, I'm lost. Security isn't really a concern, as the form captures information which is in no way sensitive. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to use the `failure` function, you can skip the AJAX method (which is a bit heavier), so I would recommend you make use of the [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) syntax of `jQuery`.

Pre-defined syntax: `jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`

Here is the example for **jQuery**:

```
$.post('../controllerMethod', { field1: $("#id").val(), field2 : $("#id2").val()}, 
    function(returnedData){
         console.log(returnedData);
});
```

Otherwise, you could use the **AJAX** method:

```
    function yourJavaScriptFunction() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../controllerMethod",   //URL to controller method you are calling.
            type: "POST",                 //Specify if this is a POST or GET method.
            dataType: "html",
            data: {                       //Data goes here, make sure the names on the left match the names of the parameters of your method you are calling.
                'field1': $("#id").val(), //Use jQuery to get value of 'name', like this.
                'field2': $("#id2").val() //Use jQuery to get value of 'name2', like this.
            },
            success: function (result) {
                //Do something here when it succeeds, and there was no redirect.
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @KaribouOfDoom Glad I could help :) Just for interest sake, did you go for the AJAX or the jQuery method?

Comment: AJAX, just because the failure function is useful.  Might be the first AJAX method I've ever used!  I have sooooo much more to learn, lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
function init()
{
    var str1 = <?php echo varname; ?> //to access the php variable use this code//
    document.getElementById('id').value= str1;
}

<body onload="init()">//make sure you call the function init()`
```

did you try something like this